# Lucene searches are slow via AzureDirectory

Tags: lucene.net, azure-blob-storage, azure-web-roles, lucene

I'm having trouble understanding the complexities of Lucene. Any help would be appreciated.

We're using a Windows Azure blob to store our Lucene index, with Lucene.Net and AzureDirectory. A WorkerRole contains the only IndexWriter, and it adds 20,000 or more records a day, and changes a small number (fewer than 100) of the existing documents. A WebRole on a different box is set up to take two snapshots of the index (into another AzureDirectory), alternating between the two, and telling the WebService which directory to use as it becomes available.

The WebService has two IndexSearchers that alternate, reloading as the next snapshot is ready--one IndexSearcher is supposed to handle all client requests at a time (until the newer snapshot is ready). The IndexSearcher sometimes takes a long time (minutes) to instantiate, and other times it's very fast (a few seconds). Since the directory is physically on disk already (not using the blob at this stage), we expected it to be a fast operation, so this is one confusing point.

We're currently up around 8 million records. The Lucene search used to be so fast (it was great), but now it's very slow. To try to improve this, we've started to IndexWriter.Optimize the index once a day after we back it up--some resources online indicated that Optimize is not required for often-changing indexes, but other resources indicate that optimization is required, so we're not sure.

The big problem is that whenever our web site has more traffic than a single user, we're getting timeouts on the Lucene search. We're trying to figure out if there's a bottleneck at the IndexSearcher object. It's supposed to be thread-safe, but it seems like something is blocking the requests so that only a single search is performed at a time. The box is an Azure VM, set to a Medium size so it has lots of resources available.

Thanks for whatever insight you can provide. Obviously, I can provide more detail if you have any further questions, but I think this is a good start.

Comment: Did you ever discover why you have such slow performance with the AzureDirectory library? I am experiencing very poor performance just adding a handful of records.

Comment: I'm afraid not. We eventually switched technologies to Elastic Search and use their built-in insertion methods without any problem. It still uses Lucene behind the scenes, but the details are hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I have much larger indexes and have not run into these issues (~100 million records).

- Put the indexes in memory if you can (8 million records sounds like it should fit into memory depending on the amount of analyzed fields etc.)  You can use the RamDirectory as the cache directory
- IndexSearcher is thread-safe and supposed to be re-used, but I am not sure if that is the reality.  In Lucene 3.5 (Java version) they have a SearcherManager class that manages multiple threads for you.
  http://java.dzone.com/news/lucenes-searchermanager
- Also a non-Lucene post, if you are on an extra-large+ VM make sure you are taking advantage of all of the cores.  Especially if you have an Web API/ASP.NET front-end for it, those calls all should be asynchronous.